# Suppress save changes prompt from Worksheet.BeforeDoubleClick Event

Tags: excel, vba

I can suppress the save changes prompt when I double-click on a cell to close Excel; how can I prevent the `new code` from overriding that?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    If Target.Address(False, False) = "U1" Then
        Cancel = True
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        Application.Quit
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    ThisWorkbook.Saved = True
    With Application                                '<< New code
        .CommandBars.ExecuteMso "MinimizeRibbon"
        .DisplayFormulaBar = False
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    With Application                                '<< New code
        .CommandBars.ExecuteMso "MinimizeRibbon"
        .DisplayFormulaBar = True
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried `Application.EnableEvents = False` ?

Comment: Yes: in each of the subroutines.

Comment: For each open workbook, set its Saved property to True and close it. Then Excel should quit without need for any messages.

Comment: I already do that in the Workbook.Open event, but the new code overrides it.